# VALIDITY of Access token in facebook graph api

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-access-token

If I have an access token then, can I somehow parse it to know at what time it will expire?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Facebook's Debug Tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) to check this if it's a small number of tokens

The expiry is also given to you along with the token at the point in the [Authentication](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/) flow where you obtain the token itself - so ideally you'd store the expiry at that time and keep it up to date when you get a new token or extend the current token